# Hiding the user's cursor over iframe. Possible?

Tags: css, iframe, mouse-cursor

I want the user's cursor to be hidden over an iframe.

```
iframe {
  cursor: none;
}
```

However it doesn't do the trick.

Do I need to use JavaScript? Can JavaScript even do it? What's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I had to resort to js for this one.

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDoc.body.style.cursor = 'none';
```

This won't work cross-domain, but I don't think you should be using something like that cross domain anyway.

Assuming this is all on your own domain, another good js solution would be to inject a stylesheet into the iframe, changing it's own css to `cursor: none` on the html or body. I have used a similar strategy for my content manager - I load the real page right into the admin panel, inject some elements and a stylesheet into it, and then have admin features available right on the site - loaded in the iframe.

Comment: This one is correct but as the author said it can raise CORS issues.

Answer (score 11):

You could also do it without JavaScript.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dyV7L/

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.hide-cursor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <iframe src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
  <div class="hide-cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one doesn't fully cover a versatile range of uses. What if the user still needs to interact with the iframe? pointer-events:none would simply stop the div from having its intended effect.

Comment: Interacting into the iframe without a cursor will lead to a bad user experience isn't it?

Comment: pointer-events:none, makes the cursor return to its normal behavior (no more custom one)

Answer (score -1):

I think the only solution without srcipts: create a div, set position: absolute to the div and Iframe, and set the div over the ifram with z-index.
Example:

```
iframe{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    display:block;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position:absolute;
}
div{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    z-index: 1;
    display:block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:none;
}
```

Comment: Same concept as @Florent's answer, but his is far better.